# The effect of the Hodge $\star$ operator on the symplectic structure of a Kahler $4$ manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Let $(M,\omega, J, g)$ be a $4$ dimensional Kahler manifold. Put $\omega'=\star \omega$ where $\star$ is the Hodge operator associated the metric $g$.

Is $(M,\omega ')$ a symplectic manifold? Is it necessarilly symplectic equivalent to the original structure $(M,\omega)$?Namely, is thete a diffeomorphism $f$ which carries $\omega ' $ to $\omega$?

Comment: Yes, because $\omega '=\omega $.

Comment: @abx Thank you! I am aware of Darbeux charts for symplectic manifolds. But is there a Kahler chart for Kahlerian manifolds? That is a chart which preserves all 3 structures in their standard Euclidean forms.

Comment: Yes. You can see that (for instance) in Weil's "Variétés kählériennes".

Comment: @abx Thanks for this reference. So what about the same question without Kahlerian assumption?

Comment: I would guess it is the same — the equality is checked at each point, the fact that $\omega$ is closed plays no role.